# JBoss EAP 6, describing runtime JVM usage

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I may be somewhat blind but cannot find any documentation related to the JBoss EAP 6 admin console JVM monitoring statistics. I am wondering about these:

"Heap Usage" and "Non Heap Usage", and the sub-categories "used, committed, init"

Answer (score 1):

In EAP 6, you can get the JVM Memory details in **bytes** via cli.
To be specific, try the following command after connecting to your JBoss using CLI:

```
/core-service=platform-mbean/type=memory/:read-resource(recursive=true,proxies=true,include-runtime=true,include-defaults=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exist in the admin console afaik. You need to use something like VisualVM, JConsole or a JBoss Monitoring or the CLI to get information about the memory in use.